# Vin and Vdd MOSFET driver

Tags: voltage, mosfet, current, motor, mosfet-driver

The [user guide](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MIC4606%20Evaluation%20Board%20UG%2050002980A.pdf) of this MOSFET driver states to turn on VDD first (power to the MIC4606), then VIN (the bridge bus voltage).

[image]

However, the datasheet shows a block diagram of a typical application circuit showing VIN feeding both the h-bridge bus and a switching power supply (MIC28511) which feeds the VDD of the gate driver. The MIC28511 has a 5mS soft start internal to the device. If we look at the voltage sequencing of the system, the implication is that VDD is delayed as VIN (aka bridge bus voltage, VBUS) is rising. Does VIN to the driver need to be present prior to a voltage being established on the h-bridge?

Comment: An unpowered bridge driver will not try to turn on any of the MOSFETs.  Often there is an external 100k resistor from Gate to Source on each MOSFET that helps hold off the MOSFETs during power up and down.  I don't know that Gate Driver, but I power up the MOSFETs before the Gate Driver in some applications.  Many times the "VDD supply" comes up long after the high power supply.

Comment: @ronsimpson, thank you for comment. Can you please tell me what you mean by "hold off" for the 100k resistor? In your final statement like, you mention that the MOSFETs drain terminal should be provided power first and then only the GATE, right? Any specific reason?